# Как синхронизировать ширину ячеек в таблице под ширину других ячеек из другой таблицы

Tags: html, css

У меня есть несколько таблиц. В одном ряду три таблицы. Под одной(первой) таблицей ещё две. Мне нужно, чтобы ячейки этих трёх таблиц(те, что под бетоном) были одной длины при изменении расширения экрана, но в первом ряду другие две таблицы не меняли своего размера.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tables-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

td {
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="tables-wrapper">
      <table>
        <caption style="font-size: 130%">
            Бетон
        </caption>
        <tbody>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Тип Бетона
              </td>

              <td>
                Цена за 1м2
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Бетон M-100 / В 7.5 с пластификатором
            </td>
            <td>
              3200р
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Бетон M-150 / В 10 с пластификатором
            </td>
            <td>
              3300р
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Бетон M-200 / В 15 с пластификатором
            </td>
            <td>
              3500р
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Бетон M-250 / В 20 / W4-8
            </td>
            <td>
              3800р
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Бетон M-300 / В 22.5 / W4-8
            </td>
            <td>
              4000р
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Бетон M-350 / В 25 / W4-8
            </td>
            <td>
              4200р
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Бетон M-400 / В 30 с пластификатором
            </td>
            <td>
              4600р
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Бетон M-450 / В 35 с пластификатором
            </td>
            <td>
              5000р
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Бетон M-500 / В 40 с пластификатором
            </td>
            <td>
              5200р
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table>
        <caption style="font-size: 130%">
            Щебень
        </caption>
        <tbody>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Тип Песка
              </td>
              <td>
                Цена за тонну
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Песок
            </td>
            <td>
              1100р
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table>
        <caption style="font-size: 130%">
            Другие стройматериалы
        </caption>
        <tbody>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Стройматериал
              </td>
              <td>
                Цена за тонну
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Песок
            </td>
            <td>
              1100р
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Отсев
            </td>
            <td>
              700р
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                 РОМ-50 на отсеве
                </td>
                <td>
                  2600р
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                 РОМ-75 на отсеве
                </td>
                <td>
                  2700р
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                 РОМ-100 на отсеве
                </td>
                <td>
                  2900р
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                 РОМ-150 на отсеве
                </td>
                <td>
                  3300р
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                 РОМ-200 на отсеве
                </td>
                <td>
                  3600р
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                 РПМ-50 на песке
                </td>
                <td>
                  3400р
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                 РПМ-75 на песке
                </td>
                <td>
                  3500р
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                 РПМ-100 на песке
                </td>
                <td>
                  3600р
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                 РПМ-150 на песке
                </td>
                <td>
                  4000р
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                 РПМ-200 на песке
                </td>
                <td>
                  4200р
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: А зачем дублировать [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1398587)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал ещё одну таблицу и в ней бы разместил ваши, тем самым сохранив размер ячеек, относительно строк.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tables-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.tables-wrap > thead {
  font-size: 130%;
  text-align: center;
}

.tables-wrap > tbody > tr {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tables-wrap table td {
    width: 100%;
  font-size: 120%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table class="tables-wrap">
  <thead>
    <td>Бетон</td>
    <td>Щебень</td>
    <td>Другие стройматериалы</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>Тип Бетона</td>
                <td>Цена за 1м2</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Бетон M-100 / В 7.5 с пластификатором</td>
              <td>3200р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Бетон M-150 / В 10 с пластификатором</td>
              <td>3300р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Бетон M-200 / В 15 с пластификатором</td>
              <td>3500р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Бетон M-250 / В 20 / W4-8</td>
              <td>3800р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Бетон M-300 / В 22.5 / W4-8</td>
              <td>4000р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Бетон M-350 / В 25 / W4-8</td>
              <td>4200р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Бетон M-400 / В 30 с пластификатором</td>
              <td>4600р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Бетон M-450 / В 35 с пластификатором</td>
              <td>5000р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Бетон M-500 / В 40 с пластификатором</td>
              <td>5200р</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>Тип Песка</td>
                <td>Цена за тонну</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Песок</td>
              <td>1100р</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>Стройматериал</td>
                <td>Цена за тонну</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Песок</td>
              <td>1100р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Отсев</td>
              <td>700р</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>РОМ-50 на отсеве</td>
              <td>2600р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>РОМ-75 на отсеве</td>
              <td>2700р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>РОМ-100 на отсеве</td>
              <td>2900р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>РОМ-150 на отсеве</td>
              <td>3300р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>РОМ-200 на отсеве</td>
              <td>3600р</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>РПМ-50 на песке</td>
              <td>3400р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>РПМ-75 на песке</td>
              <td>3500р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>РПМ-100 на песке</td>
              <td>3600р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>РПМ-150 на песке</td>
              <td>4000р</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>РПМ-200 на песке</td>
              <td>4200р</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло. Хотел бы узнать - что означает >? Например в .tables-wrap > tbody > tr {

Comment: Выбирает только дочерние селекторы - [Дочерние селекторы | htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/child)

Comment: Благодарю вас. ОЧень помогли